# the App Threadcontext design pattern

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to use this concept:

https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/212776

I've posted this question on the vaadin boards last week and I still have no joy so im trying to see if any of you have an idea.  In the post where he is showing the code, he mentions in the sentence prior this:

> Also, an important point related to ContextHelp is to have one
>   instance of ContextHelp attached to the application main window, and
>   have it accessible to code via the App ThreadContext pattern.

I can't find any documentation that shows what that pattern is and how to implement it.  Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think he refers to the ThreadLocal pattern. Book of Vaadin has a section about it, see [12.14.3. ThreadLocal Pattern](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.global.html).